# Ruby on Rails: Show default result before using dropdown filter with will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I can display the results by 10, 15, or 20 by using a drop-down. The issue is when the app loads it displays all results. I would like to display only 10 results by default before using the drop-down filter to display more results.

Can someone help please?

Thank you!

This is my VIEW:

```
<%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,15,20], @per_page), :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location='?per_page='+this.value;}" %>
```

This is my CONTROLLER:

```
@per_page = params[:per_page] || Post.per_page
    @posts= Post.all.paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
```

Comment: can you show the `Post.per_page` method definition please and tell me... when you load the app what is the value of `@per_page` variable? try to print it on the view with  `puts @per_page.inspect` and tell me what is the result on the first load

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@per_page = params[:per_page] || Post.per_page
@posts= Post.paginate(per_page: @per_page, page: params[:page])
```

Note that I call paginate without on `Post` class itself and not on result of `Post.all`.

I also removed the last `|| 10` part. I think you don't need it there as you already set this value on `Post` model.

Comment: Hey psantos, thanks for the response. I tried your code but the issue is the same.

Comment: @O.Zak take a look at my comments at your post